# For a shopping app, what are the pros/cons to building ONE model or TWO models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**Additional context:**

User can buy one or more items every time they shop. I'm trying to figure out the pros/ cons of two approaches. I've written out what I think are the Pros of each (no need to call out Cons since a Con of one can be written as the Pro of the other), but I want to get feedback from the community

**Approach 1:**

Build a single model, e.g., Items, where there is a record for every item in the transaction.

Pros:

- Generally simpler, one model is always nice
- Aligns well with the fact that items are priced and cancelled/ refunded individually (i.e., there's not really anything discount or fee occurring at the Purchase level that would either 1) not be allocated to individual items or 2) not merit its own model)

**Approach 2:**

Build two models, e.g., Purchases and Items, where Purchases is a parent record that represents that transaction, and Items are the child records that represents every item bought in that transaction.

Pros:

- For the business, I think it's easier in two ways: 1) it's easier to run analytics to figure out for example how many items people want to buy each time they make a purchase transaction (this isn't impossible with Approach 1, but certainly easier with Approach 2), and perhaps most importantly: 2) from a fulfillment perspective, it seems easier to send the fulfillment center one Purchase with many items since the delivery dates will all be the same, rather than a bunch of Items that they then have to aggregate (again it's not impossible with Approach 1, but much easier with Approach 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can get quite complicated, and in the past I've used far more advanced versions of #2. You want to normalise your data as much as possible (lookup database normalisation for further info) to make it easier to run reports, but also to maintain consistency of data and reduce duplication. In some real-world scenarios, it's not always possible to fully normalise, and processing performance considerations also play a part simetimes - if you fully normalise data, you split your data into many small chunks (e.g. rows in tables) but to reconstruct your data you then have to retrieve it from many locations (e.g. multiple database queries) which has a performance hit.

Go with #2, and thoroughly plan how you are going to structure your data before you get too far into coding it. For a well-structured model, it should be reasonably straightforward to expand on the system in future. A flat structure can become a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: yes you articulated much better than i the trade off between normalization and performance. I asked this question because I'm redesigning an app, but the initial version had 5 tables to support #2 and it was kind of annoying. But I'll still go with it, thanks!